# java morse code probelm using constructors

Tags: java, morse-code

I have a java morse code assignment using constructors. I got the code working but having a hard time calling the constructor.

1. My original code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class morseTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    char alphabet[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
    'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 
    'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0',
    ',', '.', '?' };
    

    String morse[] = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", 
            ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".---.", "--.-", ".-.",
            "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", ".----",
            "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.",
            "-----", "--..--", ".-.-.-", "..--.." };    



    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();    
    
    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();

    String str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        for (int index = 0; index < alphabet.length; index++) {
            if (alphabet[index] == chars[i]) {
                str = str + morse[index] + " ";
            }
        } 
    }
    System.out.println(str);
    sc.close();
    }
    
}
```

2. I have to call and implement a method stringToMorse() from MorseCode.java from Demo.java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // PLACE CODE HERE
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        MorseCode message = new MorseCode(input);

        System.out.println(message.stringToMorse());
        
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MorseCode {
    private static char[] alphabet;
    private static String[] morse;
    private static String input;

    public MorseCode() {
        // PLACE CODE HERE

        char alphabet[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
        'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 
        'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0',
        ',', '.', '?' };
     

        String morse[] = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", 
                ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".---.", "--.-", ".-.",
                "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", ".----",
                "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.",
                "-----", "--..--", ".-.-.-", "..--.." };              
    }
    
    MorseCode(String s) {
        input = s;
    }

    public static String stringToMorse(String s) {
         // PLACE CODE HERE

         char[] chars = input.toCharArray();

         String str = "";
         for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
             for (int index = 0; index < alphabet.length; index++) {
                 if (alphabet[index] == chars[i]) {
                     str = str + morse[index] + " ";
                 }
             } 
         }
         return s;
    }
```

When compiling, I got the error messsage

Demo.java:13: error: method stringToMorse in class MorseCode cannot be applied to given types;
System.out.println(message.stringToMorse());
^
required: String
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Comment: this has nothing to do with constructors. also, you shouldn't put those declarations in your constructors, they 're not going to change between instances

Answer (score 0):

`public static String stringToMorse(String s)`
This method needs one argument.

While invoking `message.stringToMorse()` there is no argument passed to it.

Also , In code stringToMorse method is declared as static, so it can be call  via className. Please refer below code changes.

```
public class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // PLACE CODE HERE
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    System.out.println(MorseCode.stringToMorse(input));
    
   }
}
```

Code for MorseCode class has an error in stringToMorse method. It is returning variable **s** which is nowhere declared.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MorseCode {
private static char[] alphabet ={ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 
'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0',
',', '.', '?' };


 private static String[] morse= { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", 
        ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".---.", "--.-", ".-.",
        "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", ".----",
        "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.",
        "-----", "--..--", ".-.-.-", "..--.." };              
    

public static String stringToMorse(String input) {
     // PLACE CODE HERE

     char[] chars = input.toCharArray();

     String str = "";
     for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
         for (int index = 0; index < alphabet.length; index++) {
             if (alphabet[index] == chars[i]) {
                 str = str + morse[index] + " ";
             }
         } 
     }
     return str;
}
```

Comment: I changed it to what you suggested and was able to compile. But now I received another error message. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at MorseCode.stringToMorse(MorseCode.java.31) at Demo.main(Demo.java:11)

Comment: of course you don't, because you are instantiating alphabet[] and morse[] only as local variables in your constructor, but not the ones you should be using.

Comment: As you have declared the morse and alphabet as static variables you can also initialize it directly at the time of declaration only. I have modified above code. Could you please try with it .

Comment: As morse and alphabet are static class members, We don't need to initialize every time a new object is created. Currently, you have only declared those variables not initialized it anywhere. Constructors don't get calls until you create the object of the class. The variables which you have declared in constructor are local variables , you wont be having access to those variables outside the constructor block.